# Remove file extension from each item in the array c#

Tags: c#

I have an array with items having names with .txt.
I want to remove the extension. The following code is not working.

```
var xx = filenames.ForEach(x =>
{
    int fileExtPos = x.LastIndexOf(".");
    if (fileExtPos >= 0)
        x = x.Substring(0, fileExtPos);
});
```

Can anyone help what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You can use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("filename")

Comment: `"The following code is not working."` -- Why is it not working?  Is there an error?  Are the results wrong?  Also, in the future dont use the `.ForEach()` extension method.  Use a `foreach` loop

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. For example, I am surprised if the above code compiles if `filenames` is an array. Also, do you want the filenames (without extension) to be **written back** to the array? Or do you want to project that to a new list / array? Or something else?

Comment: `var names = filenames.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);`

Answer (score 6):

There is a build in method `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` which could be used. That's the common way to handle this.

```
var result = filenames.Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);
```

You error appears here `var xx = filenames.ForEach` because `ForEach` has no return value (`void`) which could be assigned to `var xx`.